# Dictionary Query Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a dictionary of a load of questions and answers. The questions are the keys and the values are the answers. I am trying to print 15 of the 800 questions out at a time with their values which have to match the question which is why I am using a dictionary and not a list. I have included a simpler sample of the code to make it clearler what I want. This is only a small sample of my **800 questions**. The ones I have are muliple choice so **A,B,C,D**

```
My_dict = {'What is your name?':'Emma','What is your age':34,'What color eyes do you have':'Blue'}

for i in range(3):
    print(next (iter(My_dict.keys())))
```

What I get when I run it is this

```
What is your age
What is your age
What is your age
```

What I want is this

```
What color eyes do you have
What is your age
What is your name?
```

This is fine for a small dictionary howver as I said above I have **800 Questions** **I only wish to print 15 at a time which is where I run into the problem.** So far all I have been able to do is print 1 question 15 times or the dictionary 15 times. **What I want is 15 keys and their values from the dictionary **

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are creating 15 separate iterators, each one starting over at the beginning. Try creating only one iterator and calling `next` only on that.

```
My_dict = {'What is your name?':'Emma','What is your age':34,'What color eyes do you have':'Blue'}

x = iter(My_dict.keys())
for i in range(3):
    print(next (x))
```

Result:

```
What color eyes do you have
What is your name?
What is your age
```

---

Note, however, that "What is your name?" did not print first, despite being the first key appearing in the dictionary literal in the first line of your code. This is because dictionaries are unordered; when iterating over a dictionary's keys/values, Python is free to yield items in whatever order it pleases. If you need the questions printed in a particular order, consider using `collections.OrderedDict`.

```
import collections
My_dict = collections.OrderedDict((('What is your name?','Emma'),('What is your age',34),('What color eyes do you have','Blue')))

x = iter(My_dict.keys())
for i in range(3):
    print(next (x))
```

Result:

```
What is your name?
What is your age
What color eyes do you have
```

Or it may be preferable to not use a dictionary at all, if you don't particularly need constant-time access to an answer given the content of the question:

```
my_tuple = (('What is your name?','Emma'),('What is your age',34),('What color eyes do you have','Blue'))

for i in range(3):
    print my_tuple[i][0]
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens because in each iteration of your for loop, you create a new iterator over `My_Dict.keys()`, which doesn't change. Therefore, the first element of that iterator is always the same.

What you could do instead, is to create the iterator first, and THEN query it:

```
my_iter = iter(My_Dict.keys())
for i in range(15):
    q = next(my_iter)
    a = My_Dict[q]
    print("Question:", q)
    print("Answer:", a)
```

Now, that answers the question you asked, but let's clean it up a little:

In python3, you don't need to `iter` over `dict.keys()`, as `dict.keys()` returns something that looks like an iterator anyways. Also, rather that iterate over the keys and query the dict to get the value, we can simply iterate over `dict.items()`. Finally, we don't have to do iterate over `range(15)` and get each q/a pair within the loop - that's what `zip` is for:

```
for i, (q,a) in zip(range(1,16), My_dict.items()):
    print("Question", i, ":", q)
    print("Answer:", a)
```

Comment: You can just use `enumerate`: `for i, (q, a) in enumerate(My_dict.items(), start=1)`.

Comment: @chepner: valid point, but OP wants 15 entries. Enumerate would get ALL (potentially >15) of them